# Integral of $x^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, eulers-number-e

I was just wondering if there was a way to find the integral of $x^{\frac{1}{x}}$, either as a function or a value for between $0$ and $\infty$, although I think this is unbounded, as graphically the function seems to asymptote to $y = 1$. I am guessing that this is probably non-elementary, but if anyone knows something about this, (or can even prove that it asymptotes), I would be interested to find out.
Thanks.

(I have included a tag on $e$, because $x = e$ is the maximum value of the function.)

Comment: According to wolfram alpha, there is no indefinite integral: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x%5E%281%2Fx%29

Comment: Your proof that this integral equals $+\infty$ is of course correct. Your question is unclear. What else (if any) do you want, what for, and what did you try?

Comment: Of course the indefinite integral $\int x^x\,dx$ "exists".  But it is not an "elementary function".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to integrate the nth root of n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163266/how-to-integrate-the-nth-root-of-n)

Answer (score 2):

Although it seems there is not a formula for the indefinite integral of such a function, you can say for sure that

$$\int_1^{\infty} x^{\frac{1}{x}} = +\infty.$$

Indeed, $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\frac{1}{x}} = 1$ implies so. See [Divergence of improper integral if f has limit $l>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3645177/divergence-of-improper-integral-if-f-has-limit-l0) and [Limit at infinity of x^(1/x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933136/limit-at-infinity-of-x1-x) for reference.